# What is the song in My Hero Academia season 3 episode 1 at 20:00?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In season 3 episode 1 of *My Hero Academia*, (episode 39 "Game start") a song plays at 20:00.

What is that song?

Answer (score 1):

Hey anyone wondering what it was, it is called 'my hero Acedamia' 
Link: https://youtu.be/vYsfWTPwT6s